# How to add a list to a SQL database (using java)

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am new to sql and I was wondering how i can add a list to a database.  Here is what I mean:

I have an a java class like this that i want to insert its info into a db:

```
public class Dog{

  private int dog_id;
  private String dog_name;
  private ArrayList<String> dog_friends;

}
```

Every dog object will have a different amount size of friends.  My question is how i can add this list to the db.  I was planning on having 3 columns (id,name,list), I just dont know how to add a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have is, in the relational database world, called a one-to-many relationship, and it requires two database tables to represent the information.

In your first table, you'll have `id` and `name`; in your second table you'll have `dog_id`, `friend_id` and `dog_friend`.

There will be possibly many entries in the second table for every entry in the first table. When you insert a row in the second table, be sure to set `dog_id` to match the `id` in the first table.

With this structure, you can use `JOIN`s in your SQL query to get all the information at once, or query the tables independently, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks!! Cleared it up a lot!! ill look into that!

Comment: @Mark I don't think this is supposed to be a one-to-many relationship, since friendship is usually symmetric. In fact, if this is really meant to be a many-to-many relationship, then there should be an association table with dog_id and friend_id attributes. Otherwise (in case this should be a one-to-many relationship) the second table should contain only the dog_id and a string, since string is a value type.

Answer (score 3):

Your table structure should look like this (ish):

```
dogs
id: int(11)
name: varchar(255)

dog_friends
dog_id: int(11) 
dog_friend_id: int(11)
```

You don't need a dog_friend and a friend_id in the second table, assuming dog_friends are other dogs. Both dog_id and dog_friend_id will be references to the ID field in the dog table.

However, @Mark Elliot is correct in that you will use JOINs to access the data.

Also, you should read up on relational databases, in general, before venturing too far into SQL. Learning WHY is better than learning HOW. Hope this helps!

Comment: Where are you storing the String values from `dog_friends`?

Comment: I was assuming the `dog_friend` strings were names of other dogs that were friends. You wouldn't need them in the relational model, if that's the case. The `dog_friend_id` would give you the dog friend and then you could get the name through the join.