# Add an array to a SQL database (java)

Tags: java, android, sql, arrays

I want to add a list of values of a variable size in a row of a single SQL database. As i understood from the following topic, it's not possible with a `List<>` object:

[How to add a list to a SQL database (using java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638092/how-to-add-a-list-to-a-sql-database-using-java)

But it works with a String, which is basically an object containing an array of char:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MyDB.COLUMN_NAME, contact.getName());
mDb.insert(MyDB.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
```

So is it possible to add an array of an other type (like `double[] myList` , possibly contained in an object) in the database, the same way as we added TEXT?

I am using java on Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to convert your array/list to a JSON string and insert in the database. While reading the data, you can then parse it and create an array or a list.

Comment: right, it's a good idea, i keepit in mind!
but JSON is not the best efficiency for storage and computation cost, I would prefer to keep it as long or int
I could also devide each int into bytes and cast them in char, but i feel like there is an easier way to do it

Comment: So there is no way to store an integer array in a database cell?

Comment: Not in MySQL. Not sure about other databases.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think its possible but you don't need that.

you cant save objects in Java and they save as a text so you can put that in the field as a string and read that in your java again.
but the saving string is meaningless and you have to read it with java or do some scripting.